# dont restart apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

After run sudo service apache2 restart show this error:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-08-20 07:36:07 UTC; 18s ago
Process: 27890 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 20 07:36:07 debian apachectl[27890]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bi
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian apachectl[27890]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bi
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian apachectl[27890]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian apachectl[27890]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian apachectl[27890]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian apachectl[27890]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 20 07:36:07 debian systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I install gitlab on ubunti with bitnami gitlab.

How to fix this error?

Comment: It looks like something already using this ports. Maybe try `netstat` to check what is using them or restart machine (all ports will be freed).

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your [config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html) is correct with

```
# apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Like already pointed out, it seems like the port is under use, so check which program is using it

```
# netstat -tulpn

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5170/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      5170/apache2
```

and then kill the process with

```
kill -15 <proces_id>
```